# R - how to calculate count of ID by hour and date between two date times

Tags: r

I have the following data with a different IDs that have a start date time and end date Time and I want the frequency that they are working by hour by date. I am rounding for time that are less than 5 minutes.  The IDs can log in and out  see ID 2 and 6

[image: data]

```
structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7), Start = structure(c(1682980601.9993, 
1682976528.9996, 1682981213.9999, 1682976550, 1682977034.9995, 
1682976647.9992, 1682974125.9996, 1682976497.9993, 1682979153.9993
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), End = structure(c(1683009115.9995, 
1682980675.9992, 1683010288.9996, 1683010949.9993, 1683008750.9992, 
1683007497, 1682976313.9993, 1683008357.9993, 1683008503.9998
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here is the output I am looking for:

[image]

Comment: Please include a reproducible sample of your data (not a picture), such as using the `dput` command.

Answer (score 1):

We may first truncate the start and end time, adjust end time based on your 5-min rule. This allow us to create the rolling time sequence from start to end time and eventually get the desired output by counting distinct ID.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(Start_hour=as.POSIXct(trunc(Start,units="hours")), #truncate start time to hour
         End_hour=as.POSIXct(trunc(End,units="hours")), #truncate end time to hour
         End_hour=case_when(End-End_hour>5~End_hour, #5-min rule
                            T~End_hour-3600)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  do(data.frame(ID=.$ID, time=seq(.$Start_hour,.$End_hour,by="1 hour"))) %>%  #get rolling sequence
  group_by(time) %>%
  summarise(n=n_distinct(ID)) #count distinct ID

# A tibble: 11 x 2
   time                    n
   <dttm>              <int>
 1 2023-05-01 20:00:00     1
 2 2023-05-01 21:00:00     5
 3 2023-05-01 22:00:00     7
 4 2023-05-01 23:00:00     7
 5 2023-05-02 00:00:00     7
 6 2023-05-02 01:00:00     7
 7 2023-05-02 02:00:00     7
 8 2023-05-02 03:00:00     7
 9 2023-05-02 04:00:00     7
10 2023-05-02 05:00:00     7
11 2023-05-02 06:00:00     6
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `timeplyr`.

```
# remotes::install_github("NicChr/timeplyr")
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(timeplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(Start = floor_date(Start, unit = "hour"), # Floor datetime to nearest hour
         End = End - dminutes(5)) %>% # Subtract 5 minutes from end
  mutate(lens = time_seq_len(Start, End, by = "hour")) %>% # Sequence length
  reframe(ID = rep(ID, lens), # Repeat IDs by sequence lengths
          time = time_seq_v(Start, End, by = "hour")) %>% # Time sequences
  summarise(n = n_distinct(ID), .by = time) %>%
  arrange(time)
# A tibble: 11 x 2
   time                    n
   <dttm>              <int>
 1 2023-05-01 20:00:00     1
 2 2023-05-01 21:00:00     5
 3 2023-05-01 22:00:00     7
 4 2023-05-01 23:00:00     7
 5 2023-05-02 00:00:00     7
 6 2023-05-02 01:00:00     7
 7 2023-05-02 02:00:00     7
 8 2023-05-02 03:00:00     7
 9 2023-05-02 04:00:00     7
10 2023-05-02 05:00:00     7
11 2023-05-02 06:00:00     6
```